# Animate to height 0 after replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate to height 0 and then remove after doing a replace.

Does anyone have any idea why the jquery animation is not taking place?

```
$('.dataCard').not('.focused').each(function(){
    var div = $('<div />',{
        css : { height : $(this).height() }
});
    $(this).replaceWith(div).animate({ height:0 }, function(){ $(this).remove() });
```

Comment: not enough code, plz post html as well as more javascript/jquery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).replaceWith(div);` returns `this` to the chain, which in this case is the dataCard element you just removed.

```
$('.dataCard').not('.focused').each(function () {
    var div = $('<div />', {
        css: {
            height: $(this).height()
        }
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(div);
    div.animate({
        height: 0
    }, function () {
        $(this).remove()
    });
});
```

Also note that the element you just inserted has to actually have a height to be able to animate it.

Comment: Could you please tell me why this implementation of your code is not working? https://gist.github.com/theirf/7869132

Comment: Cause there's a syntax error, remove the semicolon after `$(this).height()` -> http://jsfiddle.net/B4PSu/

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var div = null;
$('.dataCard').not('.focused').each(function(){
    var div = $('<div />',{
        css : { height : $(this).height() }
});
if (div != null) {
    $(this).replaceWith(div);
    div.animate({ height:0 }, function(){ $(this).remove() });
}
```